# be.visible assertion is failing due to element having position: fixed and being covered by another element

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, automated-tests, cypress

Assertion is as follows

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="myElement"] > path')
.should('be.visible')
```

Error is as follows:

> Timed out retrying after 12000ms: expected '' to be 'visible'
>
> This element  is not visible because it has CSS property: position: fixed and it's being covered by another element:
>
> ```js
> <svg class="coveringElement" focusable="false" 
>  aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" name="large">...</svg>
> ```

I have seen answers for this in regards to `.get` and `.click` but not when the error is the `position: fixed` error causing assertions to fail.

Desired outcome:

Being able to assert that the element is visible (not just exists) within the application.

Notes:

- The element I am asserting is visible when using the app and there is nothing visibly covering it.
- The elements I am asserting are in a dialog box
- The assertion passes if I use 'exists'
- Attempting to use `.invoke` to hide the covering element does nothing

Comment: Have you inspected and looked for the offending element? Does devtools highlight the element and show it as covering the target element?

Comment: The offending element is the parent of the element I am trying to assert as being visible. Other icons that I am testing do not show this error. The error only began after integrating the code into the main app, so the icons are now displayed within a react dialog. So there may be something being inherited that is causing the element to be seen as 'covering'.

Answer (score 3):

The `<path>` element isn't a good candidate to use when performing an action in a Cypress test such as `.click()`

It's primary purpose is to tell the browser what image to draw for the parent `<svg>` element.

Instead try clicking the `<svg>` (i.e the icon) itself

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="myElement"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried making the cy.get to just get the data-cy value, but on running, it stilll looks for the <svg> to be visible and gives the same errors.
I'm also not trying to click on the element in this test, simply assert that element/svg is visible.

Comment: If you have removed `> path` from the selector, you would now get different information from the error message. What is covering the `<svg>`?